# Not able to connect MYSQL from docker

Tags: mysql, sql, r, docker

I have downloaded a MYSQL docker image and am trying to connect to MYSQL using the host given in the IPaddress section of Docker inspect (say `172.17.0.2`), port `3306` , username `:root` , and database: `MYSQL`.

I am trying to run an R script with the following Database connection:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
       dbname = “mysql”, 
       host=“172.17.0.2”, 
       port=3306, 
       username = “root”, 
       password = )
```

But I am getting an error stating the host does not exist. I even tried using various options of host like “localhost”. But am still failing to connect, with the error message:

```
Error in .local(drv, …) :
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘172.17.0.2’ (0)
Calls: dbConnect -> dbConnect -> .local -> .Call
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to connect using `localhost`, meaning the localhost of R container, not the DB.

You can connect with the container IP directly but in case of Docker the IP changing frequently if you restart the DB the container the IP will be changed.

Better to use Docker-compose, which will keep both containers in the same network and R container will be able to connect using the name of the container.

Also, verify the logs of MySQL container is it up or you able to connect from MySQL client?

You can try something like

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
       MYSQL_USER: my_user
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass

   web:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: r-base:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

So, in this case, your MySQL connection string will be

```
dbname = “mydb”, host=“db”, port=3306, username = “root”, password =root_password
```

Or the other option is to pass host IP to the R container instead of using container IP.

```
docker run -it --add-host=db:192.168.x.x r_base_image
```

So now the host will be

```
dbname = “mydb”, host=“db”
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Mysql configuration file (my.cnf) and bind the IP address.
 something like :

```
[mysqld]

bind-address    = xx.xx.xx.xx
```

if you dont know the ip , use 0.0.0.0 
it means your host mysql can be gloabaly use for all ip addresses.